# Why don't i have vertices on the bottom of my coffee cup

Tags: vertices

I am watching the blender guru make a coffee cup and he has vertices on the bottom of his cup while I don't can someone tell why my file is down below

VIDEO:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7a0cHFs7jkw

[image]

TIMING: 13:49

Comment: Please check out my file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=POjvxzOl" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/POjvxzOl/)

Comment: you've been asked before: Please put some effort into your questions by explaining thoroughly what the problem is and what issues you have encountered. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. **use the tools from this site to upload images** so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: I don't think I need to put any more information then I already have

Answer (score 0):

Because he explains that you have 32 faces meeting into create one giant face at its end. So what he instructs you to do is to do what is basically a loop cut or extrude on the existing geometry and press <kbd>i</kbd>  with the Blender keymap settings set in your preferences to hid the formulated edges that would have been created otherwise.

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: how would I do that

Comment: Go to preferences and make sure your blender key map is set to Blender in the keymap settings. Highlight your bottom edge loop and press 'i' to scale in. It shows it right in the video.